# How does an elf's appearance translate to their actual age?

Tags: dnd-5e, aging

I want to make a young-looking wood elf who appears to be 19 in human years. I've had some major problems and arguments in the past with how elves age in relative terms to human age appearance. How old would a wood elf be, if he just started to **look** 19 from a human perspective?

Comment: To the users voting to close this as opinion-based, it requires delving into previous editions (which did a more extensive job of covering the backstory and lore of each setting), but it is *not* a matter of opinion. Too broad, perhaps, but not a question of opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**They would be 19**

> Although elves reach physical maturity at about the same age as humans, the elven understanding of adulthood goes beyond physical growth to encompass worldly experience. -phb

So at 19, they would look 19 in human years. They would be a litte over a hundred to be considered 19 like a human.

> An elf typically claims adulthood and an adult name around the age of 100 -phb

Comment: So how does an elf look at, like 234?

Comment: @RoiRoiHe'sOurBoy There’s nothing in the phb about that. In my personal opinion, they would stop aging at maturity then look growing old at the end of their life.

Comment: ah, alight. Thank you! Time to release a young boi into D&D!

Comment: You have a couple of quotes in this answer, but you didn't attribute them. Where are you quoting from?

Comment: The phb, I use Roll 20 so I don’t know the exact page number.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question really. 19, sure, but they'd also look 19 at 200 and 400 and 600...it's not until they get to be very old that get so much as smile lines.